# How do I handle CryptographicException: "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid"?

Tags: vb.net, cryptography

I am coding along with [Walkthrough: Ecrypting and Decrypting Strings in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/walkthrough-encrypting-and-decrypting-strings), found on docs.micrsoft.com. The code is as follows:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public NotInheritable Class Simple3Des

    Private TripleDes As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider


    Sub New(ByVal key As String)
        ' Initialize the crypto provider.
        TripleDes.Key = TruncateHash(key, TripleDes.KeySize \ 8)
        TripleDes.IV = TruncateHash("", TripleDes.BlockSize \ 8)
    End Sub


    Private Function TruncateHash(ByVal key As String, ByVal length As Integer) As Byte()

        Dim sha1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider

        ' Hash the key.
        Dim keyBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key)
        Dim hash() As Byte = sha1.ComputeHash(keyBytes)

        ' Truncate or pad the hash.
        ReDim Preserve hash(length - 1)
        Return hash

    End Function


    Public Function EncryptData(ByVal plaintext As String) As String

        ' Convert the plaintext string to a byte array.
        Dim plaintextBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plaintext)

        ' Create the stream.
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream

        ' Create the encoder to write to the stream.
        Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(ms, TripleDes.CreateDecryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
        encStream.Write(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length)
        encStream.FlushFinalBlock()

        ' Convert the encrypted stream to a printable string.
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)

    End Function


    Public Function DecryptData(ByVal encryptedtext As String) As String

        ' Convert the encrypted text string to a byte array.
        Dim encryptedBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedtext)

        ' Create the stream.
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        ' Create the decoder to write to the stream.
        Dim decStream As New CryptoStream(ms, TripleDes.CreateDecryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
        decStream.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length)
        decStream.FlushFinalBlock()

        ' Convert the plaintext stream to a string.
        Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray)

    End Function

End Class
```

When I run the application, I receive an error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>
> 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.

The error occurs in `TruncateHash()` on the line `ReDim Preserve hash(length - 1)`

I have searched SO and other forums for this error. I am having trouble, though, applying the fixes I have found to this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a copy/paste mistake in EncryptData function. You should be calling `TrippleDes.CreateEncryptor` instead of `TrippleDes.CreateDecryptor`

Decryptor expects aligned block of crypted data and that causes the exception.

Your error occurs on this line

```
encStream.FlushFinalBlock()
```

and not the declared

```
ReDim Preserve hash(length - 1)
```